# How to debug "ErrorException Undefined variable"?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I keep getting this error when I try to run my application in browser. It works fine with **Laravel 5.3** but not in **5.5**:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: invitationsN (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\netPol\resources\views\layouts\complainant.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\netPol\resources\views\layouts\complainant.blade.php

**View**

```
<i class="entypo-list"></i> <span
        class="badge badge-warning">{{sizeof($invitationsN)}}</span> </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<!-- TS14950193223600: Xenon - Boostrap Admin Template created by Laborator / Please buy this theme and support the updates -->
<li class="top"><p>You have {{sizeof($invitationsN)}} invitation(s)</p></li>
<li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu-list scroller">
        @forelse($invitationsN as $invitation)

            <li class="unread notification-success">
                <a href="{{url('report/'.$invitation->report->code."/?invitation=1")}}">
                    <i class="entypo-eye pull-right"></i>
                    <span class="line">
                        <strong><b>From: </b>{{$invitation->invitor->name}}</strong>
                    </span>
                    <span class="line small">
                        {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($invitation->created_at)->diffForHumans()}}
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

        @empty
        @endforelse

    </ul>
</li>
```

**Code**

```
use Net_Police\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class NotificationComposer
{
public $user;
public function __construct()
{
// $this->user = $user;
 }

public function compose(View $view)
{
    if(Auth::guest()){
        $invitationsN = [];
    }else{
        $invitationsN = Auth::user()->receivedInvitations;
    }

    $view->with([ 'invitationsN' => $invitationsN ]);
}

}
```

Comment: Just a try, but remove the array brackets in your `with()`

Comment: Make sure that you register your view composer in service provider.

Comment: @Daniel **Thank you very much. It worked. I created a ComposerServiceProvider which I did not register. That was causing the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend you can use

```
Log::debug('An informational message.');
```

You also will find different levels her :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

You just have to make a **try and catch** and inside the catch type the **Log** static method.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code this

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
  if(Auth::guest()){
      $invitationsN = [];
  }else{
      $invitationsN = Auth::user()->receivedInvitations;
  }

  return View('invitationsN');
}
```